# How to set up PHP mail() for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

Do I understand correctly what I read on the CI website for the email class that if I am using PHP mail() that I don't need to do any configuring?

Here is my email in my controller.  It is not sending.  We are on a new server and I'm wondering what if anything I need to configure.

```
$this->email->from('oemsales@xxxx.com', 'OEM Sales');
$this->email->to('shummel@xxxx.com');
$this->email->subject('Contact Page Request');
$this->email->message($message);

$this->email->send();
```

$message is defined higher up in the code.  This worked on our old server.

Comment: Quote: This worked on our old server. <-- Have you ever tested the mail() function on the new server?

Comment: Yes.  mail() works fine.

Comment: Have you tried including `$this->email->print_debugger()`? What does it say?

Comment: Solved the problem.  Not sure what I changed, but it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find following information in php.ini file. SMTP value contains the address of your mail server, you can change it to your mail server address.

[mail function]
SMTP = localhost 
smtp_port = 25